# Javascript: After Effects and Date() function returns undefined

Tags: javascript, automation, after-effects

Here's the situation.

1. My team produces an announcement video that plays every Wednesday. The intro is always the same, except for the date (text layer as "[Long Month] xx, 20xx").
2. I'm trying to write some simple automation that makes the date *always* the correct Wednesday, regardless of export date (before Wednesday forces date ahead, after Wednesday forces date ahead to *next* Wednesday).

My code works in a browser, but it's not working in After Effects. In AE it returns as *undefined.* Help! (Running After Effects 14.2.1.34)

```js
var today, day, date, month

today = new Date(Date(0));
day = today.getDay();
date = today.getDate();
month = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];


function printDate() {
  return month[today.getMonth()] + " " + date + ", " + today.getFullYear();
}


function forceWednesday() {
  if (day === 3) {
    printDate();
  } else if (day < 3) {
    var x = day;
    x = 3 - day;
    return month[today.getMonth()] + " " + (date + x) + ", " + today.getFullYear();
  } else if (day > 3) {
    var dayDiff, dateDiff, nextWed, newDate, wed
    dayDiff = day - 3;
    dateDiff = date - dayDiff;
    nextWed = today.setDate(dateDiff + 7);
    newDate = new Date(nextWed);
    wed = newDate.getDate();
    return month[newDate.getMonth()] + " " + wed + ", " + newDate.getFullYear();
  }
}

forceWednesday();
```

Comment: For me it returns `result: November 1, 2017` in AE CC 2018 and in ESTK

Comment: @fabianmoronzirfas weird! Maybe it's just the machine then?...

Comment: Have you tried to run it with estk as target application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.
[See it live on Github.](https://github.com/Joontae93/alwaysWednesday-AE-Expressions)